# SQL Server error - Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to insert rows of data into a table from another table, normal scenario.

Here's my current SQL script,

```
INSERT [dbo].[X_RPT_PORTAL_REPORTLIST] (
    [PORTAL_GROUP_ID], 
    [REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME], 
    [STANDARD_REPORT], 
    [REPORT_PACK_VERSION], 
    [REPORT_PATH]
)
VALUES (
    (SELECT ID FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST),
    (SELECT REPORT_NAME FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST),
    (SELECT STANDARD_REPORT FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST),
    (SELECT REPOPT_PACK_VERSION FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST),
    (SELECT PATH FROM ReportServer$PORTAL.dbo.Catalog)
)
```

Now my error I had return from this was:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I had a thought this maybe incorrect, but I need some pointers on getting around this.

Any help or tips, is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This issue arose because one or more of the subqueries you have used to provide the data for `VALUES()` have returned multiple records. The `VALUES()` construct is used by `INSERT` to insert one and only one record.

This usually arises when people use `WHERE` conditions such as `WHERE value = (SELECT value FROM sub_table)` and the subquery returns multiple records; hence is why the error message was versed as it was.

It is possible to follow an `INSERT` statement with a `SELECT` statement which returns the data that you want put into the table, so consider the following:

```
INSERT [dbo].[X_RPT_PORTAL_REPORTLIST] (
    [PORTAL_GROUP_ID],
    [REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME], 
    [STANDARD_REPORT], 
    [REPORT_PACK_VERSION],
    [REPORT_PATH])
SELECT
    r.ID
    ,r.REPORT_NAME
    ,r.STANDARD_REPORT
    ,r.REPOPT_PACK_VERSION
    ,c.PATH
FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST r
CROSS JOIN ReportServer$PORTAL.dbo.Catalog c;
```

Comment: I've just realised that `PATH` comes from `ReportServer$PORTAL.dbo.Catalog`. Whoops… :$

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to insert one row into a table and can therefore only have one value for each column in the row. This error means is that one or more of the SELECT statements in your VALUES() clause is returning more than one value.

Run each of the SELECT statements individually and see which of them are returning multiple rows and then constrain them with a WHERE clause where necessary until you get the single value from each of them that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is clear.  You want to switch to `insert . . . select`.  Something like this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[X_RPT_PORTAL_REPORTLIST] ([PORTAL_GROUP_ID], [REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME], [STANDARD_REPORT], [REPORT_PACK_VERSION], [REPORT_PATH])
    SELECT rl.ID, rl.REPORT_NAME, rl.STANDARD_REPORT, rl.REPORT_PACK_VERSION,
           c.PATH
    FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST JOIN
         ReportServer$PORTAL.dbo.Catalog c
         ON rl.??? = c.???;
```

It is unclear what the `JOIN` conditions are.  If there is only one path, then you might want a `CROSS JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
INSERT  [dbo].[X_RPT_PORTAL_REPORTLIST] ([PORTAL_GROUP_ID], [REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME], [STANDARD_REPORT], [REPORT_PACK_VERSION], [REPORT_PATH])   
    SELECT 
        a.ID, a.REPORT_NAME, a.STANDARD_REPORT, a.REPOPT_PACK_VERSION,
        b.PATH
    FROM 
        X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST a 
    JOIN 
        ReportServer$PORTAL.dbo.Catalog b ON XXXXXXX
```

Instead of XXXX you have to type the join condition for those two tables

Answer (score 0):

Run following queries separately. Some of them will return multiple rows which causes the error. You can use WHERE/GROUP BY/PARTITION to avoid multiple rows.

```
SELECT ID FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST
SELECT REPORT_NAME FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST
SELECT STANDARD_REPORT FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST
SELECT REPOPT_PACK_VERSION FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST
SELECT PATH FROM ReportServer$PORTAL.dbo.Catalog
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue with the query is all the subqueries are returning more than 1 records.
i.e. :
(SELECT ID FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST) line is returning more than 1 records, which is not permitted in INSERT statement.

you can use following code:

```
INSERT [dbo].[X_RPT_PORTAL_REPORTLIST] 
 ([PORTAL_GROUP_ID], [REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME], [STANDARD_REPORT], [REPORT_PACK_VERSION], [REPORT_PATH])
  VALUES (
  (SELECT top 1  ID FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST),
  (SELECT top 1  REPORT_NAME FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST),
  (SELECT top 1 STANDARD_REPORT FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST),
  (SELECT top 1 REPOPT_PACK_VERSION FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST),
  (SELECT top 1 [PATH] FROM ReportServer$PORTAL.dbo.Catalog))
```

Note: changed the column name from PATH(which is a keyword ) to [PATH]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[X_RPT_PORTAL_REPORTLIST] 
 ([PORTAL_GROUP_ID], [REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME], [STANDARD_REPORT], [REPORT_PACK_VERSION], [REPORT_PATH])
  SELECT rl.ID, rl.REPORT_NAME, rl.STANDARD_REPORT, rl.REPOPT_PACK_VERSION, c.PATH
  FROM X_RPT_REPORTINGLIST rl
  INNER JOIN ReportServer$PORTAL.dbo.Catalog c ON c.Name = rl.REPORT_NAME
```